# REPLACE INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've got a table with unique constraint on two felds.

```
CREATE TABLE `targets` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `client` SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    -- some more fields here
    `order_column` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `client_order_column` (`client`, `order_column`)
)
```

and now I want to update it so, that `order_column` will contain incremental integers, starting with `0` for every `client` value. I'm trying to make it this way:

```
replace into targets (
    `id`,
    `client` ,
    `order_column`
) 

(select     
    `id`,
    `client` ,
    0 as order_column from targets
    )
on duplicate key update
    order_column = order_column + 1
```

but getting `syntax error` on the last line. I can't realize, what's wrong, so, please, help me.

Btw: is there any better way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO targets (id, client, order_column) 
SELECT  a.id, a.client , 0 as order_column 
FROM    targets a
        ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE order_column = a.order_column + 1
```

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: But `VALUES(order_column)` is always 0!

Comment: what if you execute, `ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE order_column = order_column + 1`

Comment: The error is `Column 'order_column' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: only one (first) row is updated, and than `Duplicate entry '1-1' for key ...` is fired. That means that `a.order_column` is still 0...